# Bottom Navigation Android

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-navigationview, android-bottomnav, android-bottom-nav-view

So I seen the new PlayStaion app for android and I was wondring if I can find a library to implement a bottom navigation like it if any one know a library like this please comment.
here is a screenshot of PlayStaion Android App [image: PlayStaion Android App]

Comment: @Tim Caselijns The way your are referring is not best way to do it, thats total not professional I want to find a professional way to do it

Comment: I really don't care. If you want a better answer, ask a better question

Comment: @TimCastelijns it's just a simple question with a screenshot and if you give sely answers that's just your level of expertise

Comment: don't pretend you know what you're talking about. Go read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Use Bottom Navigation Activity.
Android Studio 2.3 is provided itself **Bottom Navigation**